# ANDROID Show a dialog when the Internet/GPS loses connectivity or is not connected

Tags: android

[EDITED]

I want to show a Splash Screen / dialog when the Internet or GPS is down or not connected so the user can't use the app until the connection is good again.

I tried with some broadcast receivers, but all had problems. One of them:

```
public class ConnectivityChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

    String status = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);

    Toast.makeText(context, status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if(status.equals("Not connected to Internet")) {
        Intent splashIntent = new Intent(context, SplashScreen.class);
        splashIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(splashIntent);
 //I also had a Toast for internet is connected
    }

}
}
```

And the util class:

```
public class NetworkUtil {

public static int TYPE_WIFI = 1;
public static int TYPE_MOBILE = 2;
public static int TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED = 0;


public static int getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (null != activeNetwork) {
        if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
            return TYPE_WIFI;

        if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
            return TYPE_MOBILE;
    }
    return TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED;
}

public static String getConnectivityStatusString(Context context) {
    int conn = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(context);
    String status = null;
    if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_WIFI) {
        status = "Wifi enabled";
    } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_MOBILE) {
        status = "Mobile data enabled";
    } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED) {
        status = "Not connected to Internet";
    }
    return status;
}
}
```

Problems: it doesn't work instantly. I usually get 5 toasts in a row when the internet is disconnected and after some time if I modify the status the connection toast stop appearing or appear after a long wait of time.

Also, how to close the Splash Screen activity when the internet is back up?

Comment: broadcast receiver sounds cool, so post your receiver and let people help you..basically just put your internet/gps checking methods in your receiver and let them return a boolean if all true then you close your app and show a dialog via activity

Comment: @Juvie22 Do you have problems in detecting when the Internet/GPS connectivity is lost? Or you can detect it correctly, but have problems in showing the dialog?

Comment: @Elltz edited with more info

Comment: @ana 01 The broadcast receiver doesn't work instantly

Comment: did u specified receiver in manifest.

Comment: @SelvaYakshis yes, I registered it in the manifest

Comment: @SelvaYakshis if it wasn't it would not show up in the first place.. Juvie your problem is the delays? what is the duration you specify for setrepeating? on your broadcast receiver? receivers in api 19+ are not that instant so if you target below it, you are cool.. so main pointers is the **duration you specify** , **api level** , and **where you call your receiver** (if your receiver listens to onboot completed it will be called immediately if not you need to somewhere call it once more in your app) . last pointer is if receiver aint cool, copy all your codes to a service class.. ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a `Service` class and use `TimerTask` with `Timer` and give it a duration to start over, with this you can start your `service` from the `receiver` that you already have and make it (`receiver`) listen to `BOOT_COMPLETED` with

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
</intent-filter>
```

and specify a permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />`

and let your receiver call the service class -(or you can check your stuff there -(take into consideration the comments i made)) by implementing this in your `onReceive`

```
boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass, Context t) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) t.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

and if it returns false start service using

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
context.startService(i);
```

then in your service do this

```
public class MyService extends Service {
Timer timer; TimerTask task;
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    timer = new Timer();
    task = new TimerTask() {  
      @Override                 
      public void run() { 
          // put here your code for checking 

          String status = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);
          // i am having nesting problems so put this in a handler() ok
          Toast.makeText(context, status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          if(status.equals("Not connected to Internet")) {
          Intent splashIntent = new Intent(context, SplashScreen.class);
          splashIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
          context.startActivity(splashIntent);  
           }
        // handler() code should end here           
     };                             
    timer.schedule(task, 0, 3000);  // repeat every 3 seconds

    return START_STICKY;
  }
}
```

its getting long, to close your splash screen, you can pass an instance of your activity and make it close itself from the service, or bind to the service or use local broadcast manager

also my code closing tags might be wrong so correct them..

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution

**STEP 1:**

Make a `Java Class` named `NetworkStatus`

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class NetworkStatus 
{
    Context context;

    public NetworkStatus(Context context) 
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public boolean isNetworkOnline() 
    {
        boolean status = false;

        try
        {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) 
                    context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(0);

            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) 
            {
                status = true;
            } 
            else 
            {
                netInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(1);

                if (netInfo != null && netInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) 
                {
                    status = true;
                }
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

            return false;
        }

        return status;
    }

}
```

**STEP 2:**

Make another `Class` named `AlertDialogManager`

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.provider.Settings;
import com.lmkt.wfm.R;
import com.lmkt.wfm.activities.ActivityMainScreen;

public class AlertDialogManager 
{
    Context context;

    public AlertDialogManager(Context context) 
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void showAlertDialog(String title, final String message, final Boolean status) 
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        alertDialog.setTitle(title);

        alertDialog.setMessage(message);

        if(status != null)
        {
            alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.fail);
        }

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {   
                if(message.contains("You do not have Internet Connection"))
                {
                      ((Activity) context).finish();
                }

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

**STEP 3: Usage  from your Splash Activity:**

```
AlertDialogManager alert;

NetworkStatus ns;

ns = new NetworkStatus(context);

if(!(ns.isNetworkOnline()))
        {
            alert = new AlertDialogManager(context);

            alert.showAlertDialog("Internet Connection!", "You do not have Internet Connection. "
                    + "Please connect to the "
                    + "Internet to sync Data From Server...", false);
        }
```

Comment: yes but this doesn't check permanently for the internet status.

Answer (score -1):

**STEP 1:**
 Open **AndroidManifest.xml** and add the broadcast receiver.

```
<receiver
        android:name=".Util.InternetConnectorReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- Intent filters for broadcast receiver -->
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>`
```

**STEP 2:** create activity with dialog theme:

```
<activity
            android:name=".Activity.ActivityDialogInternet"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dark.Dialog"></activity>
```

**STEP 3:**
Make a BroadcastReceiver Class named **InternetConnectorReceiver**

```
public class InternetConnectorReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) ||
            intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE")) {
        Intent checkIntent = new Intent(context, ConnectivityCheck.class);
        context.startService(checkIntent);
    }
}}
```

**STEP 4:** Make another service class named **ConnectivityCheck** :

```
public class ConnectivityCheck extends Service {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    if (!checkConnection()) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityDialogInternet.class);
        dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(dialogIntent);
    }
    stopSelf();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

private boolean checkConnection() {
    Log.i("wudfuyf", "checking started!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetwork != null &&
            activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

}}
```

**STEP 5:** create a activity called **ActivityDialogInternet**

```
public class ActivityDialogInternet extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog_internet);
}}
```

**STEP 6:** When internet connection is turned off **ActivityDialogInternet** called and show the dialog: